# Python ranking algorithm with 30 levels

Tags: python, algorithm, ranking

I trying find a simple python-based algorithmic ranking system.

Here's the scenario:

There will be 30 levels, level 1 starts at 0 points. 2000 points are required to achieve level 30.

More points will be required as the levels progress.

For example, to go from level 1 to 2 might take 3 points. Level 2 to 3 might take 5 additional points. 
Level 29-30 might take 1200 additional points.

Since the score will be calculated on the fly, I also need a way to determine which level the player is at. For example, what level is a person with 358 points?

I could set the points manually but the 2000 point cap will fluctuate from day to day so that is not an idealistic option.

I was thinking something similar to Google's Pagerank (1-10) where it's easy to get from 0 to 4 but 9-10 is a very hard accomplishment.

Any simple snippets or tippets?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a logarithmic scale. If you want a code example:

```
base = 2 # change to change the rate at which you go through the levels
levels = 30
finalPoints = 2000
scale = levels/math.log(finalPoints, base)
level = math.floor(scale*math.log(points, base))
```

Comment: nice example. My headache suddenly went away. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The usual solution is to use a logarithmic scale. If you use log base 2, then each level needs twice as many points. If you use a log base 10, each level needs 10 times the points. This way, you can "bend" the curve. [See the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) for the math.

Comment: thanks for the tip. My attempted crash course into logarithms almost killed me, just kidding. It refreshed my memory and led me into the right direction. Thanks.